# Feynman propagators for scalar fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

If there are few massless scalar field, are the propagators of those different massless scalar fields indistinguishable?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: This question seems ill-posed in the sense that the propagator is not quite an "observable" -- since you talk about distinguishing between the different scalar fields.

Comment: I mean in terms of Feynman diagrams. If one have a Lagrangian for several interacting massless scalar fields and wants to evaluate generating functional (Z) for such interacting theory and wants to represent Z via Feynman diagrams. I think that the propagators for different massless scalar fields are depicted the same, unlike the case when we have interacting theory of e.g. scalar + Dirac field, or 2 scalar fields with different masses.

Answer (score 2):

If you have free fields which obey the same equation, the propagators are the same. So these are these propagators that you are going to use in an interacting theory to establish Feynman diagrams.

For instance, if you have an interacting term $\lambda \phi_1^2\phi_2^2$ in the Lagrangian, you will obtain, at order $\lambda$, a $4$- point Green function as :

$G(w,x,y,z) \sim\lambda \frac{\partial}{\partial J_1(w)} \frac{\partial}{\partial J_1(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial J_2(y)} \frac{\partial}{\partial J_2(z)}e^ {i \int d^4x (\Phi_1 D^{-1}\Phi_1 + \Phi_2 D^{-1}\Phi_2 + J_1\phi_1 + J_2\Phi_2)} \quad _{|J_1=J_2=0}$

where $D^{-1} = \square$ represents the inverse propagator, which is the same for the fields $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$

Comment: Off-topic remark: I'd add $\left|_{J_1=0}\right.$ right after the operator. Btw. to force a good height of |, that reads "\left|_{J_1=0}\right."